# Conditional render based on integer prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to conditionally render jsx based on the integer value of a prop. In my example below, the prop `depth` varies from `0` - `4`. The code below returns the error `Node(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` `depth` is `0`, so why won't it render? Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';

function Node({ type, name, depth }) {

  if (depth === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        {type}
        {name}
        {depth}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Node;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to return from render:

```
import React from 'react';

function Node({ type, name, depth }) {

  if (depth === 0)
    return (
      <div>
        {type}
        {name}
        {depth}
      </div>
    );

    return null

}

export default Node;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a condition inside the `return` as well:

```
import React from 'react';

function Node({ type, name, depth }) {
    return (
      {depth === 0?
        <div>
          {type}
          {name}
          {depth}
        </div>
      : null}    
    );  
}

export default Node;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return outside of if block also

```
function Node({ type, name, depth }) {
if (depth === 0) {
  return (
    <div>
      {type}
      {name}
      {depth}
    </div>
  );
}
return null;
```

}